# CGAL: k nearest neighbor periodic points

Tags: cgal, nearest-neighbor, delaunay

I want to find k nearest neighbors of a series of periodic points using **Point_set_2**, the following piece of code is the header files and related typedefs, in which I used periodic version of delaunay triangulation:

```
    #include <CGAL/Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel.h>
    #include <CGAL/Periodic_2_Delaunay_triangulation_2.h>
    #include <CGAL/Periodic_2_triangulation_traits_2.h>
    #include <CGAL/Triangulation_vertex_base_with_info_2.h>
    #include <CGAL/Point_set_2.h>
    #include <vector>

    //******************************************************************
    using namespace std;

    typedef CGAL::Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel       K;
    typedef CGAL::Periodic_2_triangulation_traits_2<K>           Gt;
    typedef CGAL::Triangulation_vertex_base_with_info_2<unsigned, Gt>  Vb;
    typedef CGAL::Periodic_2_triangulation_face_base_2<Gt> Fb;
    typedef CGAL::Triangulation_data_structure_2<Vb, Fb> Tds;
    typedef CGAL::Periodic_2_Delaunay_triangulation_2<Gt, Tds>                    Delaunay;

    typedef Delaunay::Iso_rectangle Iso_rectangle;

    CGAL::Point_set_2<K,Tds> PSet;

    typedef CGAL::Point_set_2<K,Tds>::Edge_iterator                   Edge_iterator;
    typedef CGAL::Point_set_2<K,Tds>::Vertex_handle                   Vertex_handle;
    typedef K::Point_2                                                Point_2;

    typedef vector<pair<Point_2,unsigned> > Vector;
```

and these are from the main part of the program, in which according to the [CGAL manual](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Point_set_2/group__PkgPointSet2NeighborSearch.html), I used Delaunay& T in the argument of the function **nearest neighbor()**:

```
    Vector points;
    for(int iat = 0; iat < N_b; iat++)
        {
        points.push_back(make_pair(Point_2(r_b[iat][0],r_b[iat][1]),iat));
        }
    Iso_rectangle domain(0,0,L[0],L[1]);
    Delaunay T(points.begin(), points.end(), domain);
    PSet.insert(points.begin(),points.end());



    vector<Vertex_handle>::const_iterator it;

    vector<Vertex_handle> LV;
    for(int iat = 0; iat < N_b; iat++)
        {
         Point_2 focal(r_b[iat][0], r_b[iat][1]);
         PSet.nearest_neighbors(T, focal, nei_top+1, back_inserter(LV));
         vector<Vertex_handle>::const_iterator it_begin = LV.begin()+1;
         vector<Vertex_handle>::const_iterator it_end = LV.end();


         for (it = it_begin; it != it_end; it++)
              {

               int jat = (*it)->info();
               array1[iat]+= sin(theta[jat]-theta[iat]);
               }
         LV.clear();
      }
      points.clear();
```

but it gets a bunch of errors including this one:

```
OutputIterator   nearest_neighbors(Point p, size_type k, OutputIterator res)
                    ^
/usr/include/CGAL/Point_set_2.h:180:20: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
```

In manual, I see the Dt as an argument, but according to the error, such argument doesn't exists!

Comment: Read again the [doc](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Point_set_2/classCGAL_1_1Point__set__2.html#a56335e1ea6e4f69f917a2a16c442c98c). There is no triangulation that should be given to the function. Actually the class `Point_set_2` already have an internal triangulation.

Comment: @sloriot, so how can I force Point_set_2 to use domain which is necessary for periodic calculations? I compared the results with a simple sorting algorithm, but the results aren't the same, I think Point_set_2 doesn't take into account periodicity.

Comment: It is not possible with the current implementation: `template<class Gt, class Tds = Triangulation_data_structure_2 <Triangulation_vertex_base_2<Gt> > >
class  Point_set_2 : public  Delaunay_triangulation_2<Gt,Tds>`. In practice I don't expect it to be hard to do, it just need a few modifications in the code.